# How to switch to a TTY in Virtual Box VM?

Tags: virtualbox, shortcut-keys, tty

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 VM in VirtualBox 5.0.18 and I need to switch to TTY1, how can this be achieved? Is there a keyboard shortcut to achieve this in the guest session because doing the normal one just switches to TTY1 in the host?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut in VirtualBox to switch to a TTY is (replace `X` with the number of the TTY you wish to switch to (e.g.: <kbd>F1</kbd> for TTY1)):

<kbd>Host Key</kbd> + <kbd>FX</kbd>

Normally, the Right Control key is your host key.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> after entering fullscreen mode, and back to GUI by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: No, that's for the host, I need to know for the guest.

Comment: Enter fullscreen mode, then this command should be okay.

Comment: It would be good if this was not required of me, but I have already found the answer as you probably will have seen. Thank you for your answer anyway. :)

Comment: <ctrl> + <F7> got me back to the gui from tty